# How to make sure the entire label is visible in the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I have recently started learning pyQt5 and am running into an issue where the entire label does not show up on the window. Is there a quick fix for this? This is the code I have so far and the image of the window is attached as well -> Before button click:

[image: Before button click]

After button click:

[image: After button click]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
# Create an innstance of QMainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()    # parent constructor
        self.setGeometry(400, 200, 1000, 750)     # sets size of window 
        self.setWindowTitle("The birds work for the bourgeoisie")    # sets title of window
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # stuff we want in window

        # Step 1: Define an application
        # Labels
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)   # where label is located
        self.label.setText("birb wants freedom")
        self.label.move(400,200)

        # Buttons
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("Free birb")
        self.b1.move(410,230)

        # Map button to an event
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

    # Step 2: Create event for button click
    def clicked(self):
        self.label.setText("FREEDOM AT LAST!")

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)    # passing cmmd line args to QtApp
    win = MyWindow()                # widget shown in the application
    win.show()                      # brings up window
    sys.exit(app.exec_())           # winndow shows up nicely and exits properly

window()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label object has an adjust size method. From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-how-to-auto-resize-label-adjustsize-qlabel/:

> PyQt5 – How to auto resize Label | adjustSize QLabel
> Last Updated : 26 Mar, 2020
> During the designing of the GUI (Graphical User Interface) application there is a need to display plain text as information where label is used, but sometimes information text could be large or much smaller and it is difficult to use resize() method so have to auto adjust the size of the label according to the text, in order to do so adjustSize() method can be used.

> adjustSize() method will change the size of label according to the length of the text, if the length is less it will decrease the length and height of the widget and vice versa.

> Syntax : label.adjustSize()

> Argument : It takes no argument.